# Edit text is losing focus when scrolled

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

I have a page with various edit text and spinner. To enable scroll i have put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` into my manifest with the activity. But when I am scrolling my view my focused edit text is losing focus. I mean, suppose i have first edit text focused, and i scroll down, and come back to my first edit text but now my first edit text has lost its focus. Interesting point is that when i am testing the same thing in API level4.0 its working fine, not in pre 4.0

Please help me what to do or suggest something which i losing out.

And for code, its just few edit texts which are wokring

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what android is providing, and there may be some work around, but presently this is how it works. So What I can tell you is to be with this restriction. Any update will inform you.